# EventInfo.GetRaiseMethod() always null

Tags: .net, events, reflection

I have:

```
event EventHandler MyEvent;

MyEvent += new EventHandler(someHandler);

if(this.GetEvent("MyEvent").GetRaiseMethod() == null)
{
  // Always true...
}
```

But why? After I add a handler, shouldn't `GetRaiseMethod()` be set to `someHandler`'s `MethodInfo`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a quirk of C#, it doesn't support raise accessors.  Only add and remove.  Other .NET languages like VB.NET, F# and C++/CLI do support them and it is well defined in the CLI spec, named "fire" in that one.

It is hard to explain why the C# team skipped it, I've never seen a good explanation for it.  Pure speculation: it may have had something to do with their desire to avoid the cost of constructing the event arguments for an event that nobody subscribed.  Very common in the GUI frameworks.  It is a bit of a loss, hundreds of thousands of hours must have been lost by C# programmers writing the standard raise event pattern as well as diagnosing NREs when they forgot to check for null.  The elvis operator (`?.`) in C# v6 finally made it easier.

Anyhoo, you'll never get anything but null from GetRaiseMethod() if you reflect code written in C#.  You'll however always get a non-null when it was written in VB.NET, F# or C++/CLI.  You'll have to dig out the backing delegate variable if you need to raise the event with reflection, that can be painful.  If the auto-generated add/remove accessors were used then the backing variable has the same name as the event and you can retrieve it with Type.GetField(), using BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance.

Comment: Not being very familiar with VB.NET, I tried to write some VB.NET code with an `Event`, trying to obtain a case such that `GetRaiseMethod()` returns something. I tried the `AddHandler` statement, but I tried a `Handles` clause as well. The former seems to subscribe to the event only at run-time (like in C#, I think?), but the latter seems more promising in that it declares the relation at compile-time. Still I had no success with `GetRaiseMethod`, it returns `Nothing` (null). How do I create an example to show that `GetRaiseMethod` can be non-trivial for code that comes from VB.NET?

Comment: Works fine when I try it, you'll have to ask a question about it.

Comment: To those who cannot afford reading my other (long) thread, here are my VB.NET findings. **(1)** A usual "auto" event never has a `RaiseMethod` associated (one could argue that this is an implementatiuon detail). **(2)** A `Custom Event` is required to give _three_ accessors (compared to C#'s two), the third one being `RaiseEvent(...)`, and therefore in the case of `Custom Event`, a `RaiseMethod` always exists.

Comment: **(3)** A clause `Handles` does not lead to the procedure (`Sub` method) in question being "promoted" to a raise accessor of the event. Instead it works like including an `AddHandler Event, Delegate` statement in the class constructor (`Sub New`) or type initializer (`Shared Sub New`).

Answer (score 3):

The raise method is one of the accessors mentioned in the CLI specification in addition to "add" and "remove" - however, most events simply don't implement this feature. In particular, c# specifically does not support this - so yes: that will always return null.

Comment: You might want to add that you're talking about the CLI specification, not the C# specification.