# Can EventInfo.GetRaiseMethod return an instance, when used on CIL from VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, reflection

In the thread *[`EventInfo.GetRaiseMethod()` always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885325/)*, there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887355/1336654) by well-known expert Hans Passant where he explains that if the CIL comes from VB.NET (or F# or C++/CLI), as opposed to C#, then the [method `EventInfo.GetRaiseMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.getraisemethod.aspx) will return something (i.e. an instance, a reference that is not `null` or `Nothing`).

Not being very familiar with VB.NET, I tried to write some VB.NET code with an `Event`, trying to obtain a case such that `GetRaiseMethod` returns something.

I tried the `AddHandler` statement, but I tried a `Handles` clause as well. The former seems to subscribe to the event only at run-time (like in C# with the `+=` operator, I think?), but the latter seems more promising in that it declares the relation at compile-time(?).

Still I had no success with `GetRaiseMethod`, it returns `Nothing` (null). **How do I create an example to show that `GetRaiseMethod` can return non-trivially for code that comes from VB.NET?**

Comment: You didn't post your code.  Thanks for the downvote btw, lovely, always nice to be reminded that your failure to write correct code is my problem.  Use the Custom keyword on the Event declaration so you can declare the RaiseEvent accessor.  Use BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance in the GetRaiseMethod() call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe I should not have created a new thread in the first place. However, I made this thread on the suggestion (in the other thread) of Hans Passant.

Passant's immediate comment to my question above was very helpful. Here is a piece of code that illustrates the situation:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection

Module M

    Sub Main()
        AddHandler C1.Bang, AddressOf SomeAction
        C1.Test()
        AddHandler C2.Boom, AddressOf SomeAction
        C2.Test()

        ' Check which GetRaiseMethod find something
        Dim bangRaiseAccessor As MethodInfo = GetType(C1).GetEvent("Bang").GetRaiseMethod(True)
        Dim boomRaiseAccessor As MethodInfo = GetType(C2).GetEvent("Boom").GetRaiseMethod(True)
        Console.WriteLine("M: GetRaiseMethod(True) for C1.Bang: {0}",
                          If(bangRaiseAccessor, DirectCast("<none>", Object))
                          )
        Console.WriteLine("M: GetRaiseMethod(True) for C2.Boom: {0}",
                          If(boomRaiseAccessor, DirectCast("<none>", Object))
                          )
    End Sub

    Private Sub SomeAction()
        Console.WriteLine("M: Inside 'SomeAction'.")
    End Sub

End Module

Class C1

    ' auto-event; backing delegate type, backing field and accessor methods are compiler-generated
    Shared Event Bang()

    Private Shared Sub OnBang() Handles Me.Bang
        Console.WriteLine("C1: Inside 'OnBang'.")
    End Sub

    Shared Sub Test()
        Console.WriteLine("C1: Test firing event Bang.")
        RaiseEvent Bang()
        Console.WriteLine("C1: Test finished.")
    End Sub

End Class

Class C2

    Shared Custom Event Boom As Action
        AddHandler(value As Action)
            Console.WriteLine("C2: Inside custom AddHandler accessor, 'value' contains '{0}'.",
                              If(value = Nothing, "<none>", value.Method.ToString())
                              )
            ' TODO: use parameter, for example aggregate "value" in field with delegate combination
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(value As Action)
            Console.WriteLine("C2: Inside custom RemoveHandler accessor, 'value' contains '{0}'.",
                              If(value = Nothing, "<none>", value.Method.ToString())
                              )
            ' TODO: use parameter, for example subtract "value" from field with delegate removal
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent()
            Console.WriteLine("C2: Inside custom RaiseEvent accessor.")
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    Private Shared Sub OnBoom() Handles Me.Boom
        Console.WriteLine("C2: Inside 'OnBoom'.")
    End Sub

    Shared Sub Test()
        Console.WriteLine("C2: Test firing event Boom.")
        RaiseEvent Boom()
        Console.WriteLine("C2: Test finished.")
    End Sub

End Class
```

One gets the output:

```
C1: Test firing event Bang.
C1: Inside 'OnBang'.
M: Inside 'SomeAction'.
C1: Test finished.
C2: Inside custom AddHandler accessor, 'value' contains 'Void OnBoom()'.
C2: Inside custom AddHandler accessor, 'value' contains 'Void SomeAction()'.
C2: Test firing event Boom.
C2: Inside custom RaiseEvent accessor.
C2: Test finished.
M: GetRaiseMethod(True) for C1.Bang: 
M: GetRaiseMethod(True) for C2.Boom: Void raise_Boom()
```

Conclusions:

- An "auto" `Event` will not have a **raise** accessor method, and `GetRaiseMethod` will return `Nothing`
- A `Custom Event` *requires* a **raise** accessor method `RaiseEvent(...)`, and `GetRaiseMethod(True)` returns the reflection representation (`MethodInfo`) of it
- Subscription to an event (`Custom` or not) happens at run-time, no matter if you subscribe with the syntax `AddHandler C1.Bang, AddressOf SomeAction` (in which case the subscription happens when this statement is reached, of course), or you subscribe with the syntax `Private Shared Sub OnBang() Handles Me.Bang` (in which case the subscription happens early, before any `AddHandler` statements run, and certainly before any use of the `Event Bang`)