# C# Reflection: How to invoke a EventInfo?

Tags: c#, events, reflection

how do i invoke the event behind a EventInfo ?
I tried the following but "GetRaiseMethod" is always "null":

```
MethodInfo eventRaiseMethod = eventInfos[i].GetRaiseMethod();
eventRaiseMethod.Invoke(this, arrayOfPropertyChangedArgs);
```

Thank you :)

Update: Seems thats a bug in C# ???

[EventInfo.GetRaiseMethod() always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885325/eventinfo-getraisemethod-always-null)

Comment: It's not a bug, but a design decision: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a4k4e35(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Invoking" event only makes sense if event is implemented without overriding add\remove:

```
class Test {
    public event Action TestEvent;

    void Invoke() {
        // fine
        TestEvent();
    }
}
```

However, concept of invoking for event with custom add\remove does not make sense:

```
class Test {
    public event Action TestEvent
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }

    void Invoke() {
        // does not compile, invoke what?
        TestEvent();
    }
}
```

So event invocation is just syntax sugar of calling underlying compiler-generated delegate field, for events with "default" implementation.

Knowing that, you can search for that field and invoke it. This is a private field with the same name as event:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var test = new Test();
        test.TestEvent += OnTest;            
        var backingField = typeof(Test).GetField("TestEvent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var delegateInstance = (Action)backingField.GetValue(test);
        delegateInstance();            
    }

    private static void OnTest() {
        Console.WriteLine("Event invoked");
    }
}

class Test {
    public event Action TestEvent;
}
```

That said, compilers of some .NET languages might generate "Raise" method for autoimplemented event. If that is the case - `GetRaiseMethod` will return such method. C# compiler doesn't do that though. So if you want to be safe - you might first call `GetRaiseEvent` and if it returns null - fallback to field approach. Of course you should expect field to be null also (since not all events are invocable as described above - there is not requirement for such field to exist).

Comment: An event in fact is very similar to an automated property where the compiler also generates a backing field. If you specify the event in the long form, no field is generated.

Comment: Another comment: Other .NET languages such as VB.NET do have an explicit support for the raise method. However, C# has no support for that but forces developers to work with the backing field of the event directly.